# jQuery hover states on individual posts in Wordpress loop

Tags: jquery, css, hover, wordpress

I have a page that displays multiple posts in a Wordpress loop. I've created a hover state for the posts via jQuery, targeting them by their classes and adding an ".active" class. When I hover over one of the posts, every post's hover state becomes active because they all use the same classes.

How can I make it so that only the post being hovered over displays its hover state?

I know they need to be targeted by ID, but I don't know how to apply these IDs to continuously added posts or how to make jQuery dynamically target different IDs without a new script for each one.

Thanks for the help!

Here is my loop for custom post type "team." It's a page that displays a grid of team members' photos.

```
<!--The Loop-->
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'team'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="team-grid-item">
        <div class="team-grid-title">
            <h4><?php the_field('team_member_name'); ?></h4>
            <div class="team-line"></div>
            <h4><?php the_field('team_member_title'); ?></h4>
        </div><!--.team-grid-title-->
        <div class="team-grid-color-overlay"></div>
        <div class="team-grid-image-container">
            <img class="team-grid-image" src="<?php echo get_field('team_member_photo')['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_field('team_member_photo')['alt']; ?>" />
        </div><!--.team-grid-image-container-->
    </div><!--.team-grid-item-->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>No posts here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And my script for the hover state:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".team-grid-item").hover(function(){
        $('.team-grid-title').fadeIn(300);
        $('.team-grid-color-overlay').addClass('active');    
    }, function(){
        $('.team-grid-title').fadeOut(300);
        $('.team-grid-color-overlay').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: show me your code :>

Comment: I posted the code above. Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: Damian — Thank you so much for your edits! That's how I wanted it formatted, but could not figure out why mine was wonky.

Comment: doyousmellham, I prepared answer for you, but @Sruly was first - goddamn breakfest, I shouldn't eat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use relative jquery selectors.

Once you hook the hover event you the "this" to continue the effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".team-grid-item").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.team-grid-title').fadeIn(300);
    $(this).find('.team-grid-color-overlay').addClass('active');    
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.team-grid-title').fadeOut(300);
    $(this).find('.team-grid-color-overlay').removeClass('active');
});
```

});

Comment: That solved my problem precisely! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to get behavior that you describe. If you add class `.beHovered` to elements and write this js:

```
$('.beHovered').hover(function() {
   //mouseenter code
}, function() {
   //mouseleave code
});
```

or this css:

```
.beHovered:hover {
   //hover styles
}
```

**always** only hovered element bind effect, not all.

BTW. Show me your code, please, I'm very interested how you did this: *When I hover over one of the posts, every post's hover state*